# How do I determine the amount of paint needed for a room?

Tags: paint

I'm not very handy; thus I'm very new to this. Forgive my ignorance.

Is there a proper method or means of determine how much paint is needed to paint an entire room?

Or there isn't a way because paint viscosity is very different from paint to paint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A can of paint will often indicate how much area it will cover. A general rule of thumb is 350 sq ft per gallon (as Shirlock mentions, use 250-300 sqft/gal for the first coat). Calculating the area of the walls and ceiling involves some basic math: multiply the length * width (or height) of the ceiling (or wall), then subtract any openings.

Comment: +1 : I usually figure 250 to 300 square foot first coat, and 350 for second coat etc.